# Need to check if an activity have parent activity alive or not

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-lifecycle

Let me explain what i want to accomplish.
I have SignUp Activity, Login Activity and Main Activity. Sign up activity is parent of login activity means user can go back to it if they press back softkey. and once i go from signup to main activity i clear all alive activity instance

- From Login Activity user can go to sign up activity
- From Signup Activity User can either skip sign up and go to guest mode in main activity or go back to login activity that is its parent activity in manifest
- From main activity user can go to signup activity

now my concern is if i go from sign up to guest mode in main activity [note that login activity instance will be cleared] and then click back register/sign up activity. i want to know if its coming from parent activity i.e. login activity or from main activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply put an extra to your Intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CallingActivity.this, ActivityToStart.class);
intent.putExtra("startedFrom", CallingActivity.class.toString());
startActivity(intent);
```

Make the appropriate checks in the newly started Activity:

```
if(getIntent().getExtras().getString("startedFrom", null) != null) {
 //You were started from the specified Activity
}
```

If you are starting the Activity with `startActivityForResult()` you can skip the steps above and just use `getCallingActivity()`

Comment: currently i did these intent passing extra and it works fine but only thing is i have to do checks in my newly created activity. i was wondering if there is a proper method to get the parent activity who called it. [note that im not starting that activity for result]. Thanks  :)

Comment: No there isn't. Please note that an Activitity might not be started from other Activity, but other Context as well

Answer (score 0):

You can check if are running:

```
 public boolean isRunning(Context ctx) {
    ActivityManager activityManager = 
(ActivityManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

List<RunningTaskInfo> tasks = activityManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

        for (RunningTaskInfo task : tasks) {
            if (ctx.getPackageName().equalsIgnoreCase(task.baseActivity.getPackageName())) 
                return true;                                  
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: what is 'baseActivity' here? parent activity that created new activity? thanks :)